# The JMS message does not re-delivery when it is not acknowledged?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, jms

I am deploying a JMS application, I use Message-Driven Beans to Receive Messages Asynchronously, in `onMessage` method, my logic code is called automatically when a message arrives, I have some case now that is the external resource is not ready to process this message, so I want to delay my logic in `onMessage` method, re-process it after the resource is ready.

My idea is to use CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode when creating queue session, so in onMessage method, I will check whether the external resource is ready, if not I will not acknowledge this message and expect the message will re-delivery by message provider. but whatever, the message never re-delivery? do everybody know why or my idea is wrong? any better idea?

Comment: I'm going to assume, based on your comments, that you're doing something like `message.acknowledge()`, this method is actually misleading.  Per the docs, this acknowledges everything within the session and not an individual message.

Comment: Not a good idea to use `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` with message-driven beans since acknowledgements are handled automatically by the J2EE container.